Are there finitely generated, infinite dimensional solvable Lie algebras over $\mathbb{C}$?
Solvable Lie algebras are usually assumed to be finite dimensional. The only examples of infinite dimensional complex solvable Lie algebras I have encountered are not finitely generated (as a Lie algebra). Is a finitely generated solvable Lie algebra necessarily finite dimensional? How about finitely presented Lie algebras?

Consider the infinite-dimensional graded filiform Lie algebra $L$ generated by $e_1,e_2$ with basis $e_i, i\in \Bbb N$ and relations
$$
e_i=[e_1,e_{i-1}]
$$
for all $i\ge 2$. We have $[[L,L],[L,L]]=0$, since $[e_i,e_j]=0$ for all $i,j\ge 2$. Hence $L$ is metabelian, i.e., $2$-step solvable.
